# How do I remove the AdminPage.exe program?

Tags: windows, uninstall

I installed the `AdminPage.exe` program on my laptop.

Now I would like to remove/uninstall this software, but I can't do it. I did not find the real destination of this installation. From Task Manager, I found that `AdminPage.exe` is running under `C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\AdminPage.exe`.

So, how could I remove this one from my computer?

I am using a limited account and I've also installed it from a limited account.